# How can I save the output of a http-request in an array?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, httprequest

I have an Angular application in which I am doing a http-request. The output of this request is a type: `object`. When I `console.log` the data I can see that it is an `array of objects`.

My question now is:

**How can I save the data to display it afterwards in a chart?**

Here is my code:

```js
setInterval(() => { 
        // API request
        this.service.getMesswerte().subscribe({
          next: data => {
              this.chartData = data;
              console.log(this.chartData);
          }
        })
}, 10000)
```

And here is the `console.log` output:

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 4, temperatur: 25.9, luftfeuchtigkeit: 90, co2: 20.6, becken: 83, …}
1: {id: 5, temperatur: 25.9, luftfeuchtigkeit: 90, co2: 20.6, becken: 83, …}
2: {id: 6, temperatur: 25.4, luftfeuchtigkeit: 91, co2: 19.8, becken: 80, …}
3: {id: 7, temperatur: 23.1, luftfeuchtigkeit: 90, co2: 3.8, becken: 87, …}
4: {id: 8, temperatur: 24.3, luftfeuchtigkeit: 95, co2: 120.4, becken: 98, …}
length: 5
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are the types messed up or are they ok? As to save the data to an array, what do you mean, you already have an array no? If you mean you want to increment in one big array, just do `this.charData.contact(date)`

Comment: When I make my variable chartData of the type Array<Object> instead of Object it gives me this error: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Object[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more => so I am not able to save the data as an array only as an object.

Comment: You'll need to show us your `service.getMesswerte()` function please.

Comment: getMesswerte() : Observable<object> 
 {
   return this.client.get("url");
 }

Comment: Ah, then do not type as object but object[]... Better yet, type correctly the real type not simply object.

Comment: So I should declare my variable like that: chartData!: object[]; ?

Comment: Always give the output of APIs a proper type other than `object` or `any`. You are making a contract with the provider of the API; they should be able to tell you the shape of the data that is getting returned from their API. You should be able to convert that shape to a TypeScript type (class or interface).

Comment: The shape of the data is json

Comment: `getMesswerte() : Observable<{id: number, temperatur: number, luftfeuchtigkeit: number, co2: number, becken: number, …}>` This would make your contract better. Now, you might want to read a bit about typescript and interfaces.

Comment: I think the problem is that the result of thr request is an object but I want to save it in an array.

Comment: The result of the request is whatever the JSON parser parses the JSON as. In this case, it is an array. Again, the provider of the API should be able to tell you how the data are being returned, and you should create a TypeScript type that matches that.

Answer (score 0):

i dont unterstand what you need exactly but you can store the data like that to build a chart :

```
//Add interface on the top 
export interface Result : {
id: number,
//other fields ..

}
//@Component....

  
data: any[] = [];
setInterval(() => {      
this.service.getMesswerte()
.subscribe({
          next: result=> {
      this.data = [];
      for (let row in result as Result[]) {
        this.data.push([
          result[row].temperatur,
          result[row].luftfeuchtigkeit,
      //other attr...
        ]);
      }

          }
        })
       }, 10000)
```

Comment: When I am doing this I get following error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.

Comment: i edit my code,  so you can found the shap of data in stackblitz link , the shape is like that : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b4hcqw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html is that what you need :)

Comment: I tried this and ys thats what I need. But I still get en error. The error is that the data that I get back from is of type object so I cant´t save it in an array.

Comment: Try with the edit code.. otherwise if you need to transform something just pipe to the observable and do a map to transform a shape of returned data like you want